# How to dynamically change master page's master page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have designed a module that change master page dinamically based on user log-in privileges.

I followed this tutorial :

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.it/2009/10/sharepoint-dynamically-change-master.html?showComment=1354630820782#c5132604142640789136

Everything works well. But only works on sharepoint home page. If try to go to other page like

> _layouts/user.aspx

or

> /_layouts/closeConnection.aspx

then the page would crash!

```
public class DynamicMasterPageModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {


    }


    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }


    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
            page.PreInit += new EventHandler(page_PreInit);
        }
    }
void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = sender as Page;
        string pageNo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MasterPageNo"];




        if (page != null)
        {
            if (pageNo.Equals("1"))
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/custom.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom1.master";
                }
            }
            else if (pageNo.Equals("2"))
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/custom.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/custom2.master";
                }


            }
            else
            {
                page.MasterPageFile = "~masterurl/default.master";
                if (SPContext.Current != null)
                {
                    SPContext.Current.Web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/default.master";
                }
            }


        }
```

ERROR :

```
The file '/_layouts/masterurl/custom.master' does not exist. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The file '/_layouts/masterurl/custom.master' does not exist.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): The file '/_layouts/masterurl/custom.master' does not exist.]
   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath) +11108402
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +163
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) +116
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +69
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +18
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +58
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1256
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that changes the master page? I think it might be because you are getting the url of the master page relatively, you might need to change the path a little. (You can check for a file not found in the ULS)

Comment: ok. that's the main part of the code. Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In follow up to my comment, the code is indeed lookup like it is possibly not referencing the master page properly.

The code should look more like this:

```
string masterUrl = site.ServerRelativeUrl;

if (!masterUrl.EndsWith(@"/"))
{
    masterUrl = masterUrl + @"/";
}

SPFile file = web.GetFile(masterUrl + "_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master");
```

This will give the correct permission based relative url for the master page.

Comment: Hi . I tried but no way. Seems it's not the problem. Non problem for the home page but for other gives me error!

Comment: Check the error in the logs what does it say? Please post as an edit to your question in a code block

Comment: oK. I got the error!  I modified my code block as you  told me! Thanks

Comment: Because your master page will be deployed to the catalog not layouts.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. As I said I not a sharepoint programmer. What you mean? Question: why It tries to check the master into '/_layouts/masterurl/custom.master' and for the home page it doesn't do this? ?

Comment: The code isn't looking up the master page name correctly, use the code I provided to get the url. It has to be in place of the code you are using. the ~masterurl token isn't providing the correct values.

Comment: So, I have to remove (page.MasterPageFile = ~masterurl/custom.master";) and leave only                          string masterUrl = site.ServerRelativeUrl;

 if (!masterUrl.EndsWith(@"/"))
{
  masterUrl = masterUrl + @"/";
 }

var customMaster = masterUrl + MasterAdmin;
 page.MasterPageFile = customMaster;
                                            //"~masterurl/custom.master"

Comment: Sorry it's going to be about 2 hours before I can write the code out for you. It has to replace the page line and the if statement.