# Dynamically Change Master Page in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

How to change the masterpage for different group of users in SharePoint 2013.?
i have a 10 groups in sharepoint like Group A,Group B,Group C...upto Group J.Now first user is part of Group A and he logged in to a site able to see the diff master page,and group b user is able o see the another master page.

is it possible in sharepoint?

Answer (score 4):

You can change it but you have to write code for this. Check this blog, he mentioned the complete code. He change the master page on the user login status.

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.it/2009/10/sharepoint-dynamically-change-master.html?showComment=1354630820782#c5132604142640789136

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/02/switch-sharepoint-master-page-for-logged-in-user/

also check if you have issue with above code:

[How to dynamically change master page's master page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53153/how-to-dynamically-change-master-pages-master-page)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108917/different-ways-to-automatically-apply-branding-when-a-site-is-created/108933#108933